# How to create my own network protocol to communicate in java

Tags: java, android, sockets, protocols

I want to create my own network communication protocol using java to communicate between my android app and server(I don't want use http services ) . As i don't have much more knowledge about how actually protocol works i am confused. I have seen some tutorials where they have created some protocols using socket programming , is this only way to do so?? please help .

Comment: I´d recomment you to use web/rest services as you learn and, probably you´ll stick to that in the end

Comment: could you describe more the problem and what you want to achieve, for us to know why existing protocols are not good enough for you ?

Comment: existing protocols are good enough for me but i just want to experiment the non standard ways of communication  instead of using standard protocols. So i want to find some way...

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are into the idea, you will end up by having it **on top of the HTTP protocol** (this because of its **firewall friendliness**, specially when we are talking an android server solution). Still you will need to have the required **HTTP headers**. I would recommend **take a look at REST** and see if it is good enough for you.